# Binding DB value to drop down (using editor template) issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, mvc-editor-templates

I have views created for Create, Edit, Delete. I am using an editor template to display a drop down in the view with choices from the template.

On my views (Both Create and Edit):

```
  <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) %> 
  //This is dropdown getting list from template.
```

Issue: Name field is not displayed on the Edit View.

template file (NameDropDown.ascx) looks like..

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"%>    

<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "", 
    new SelectList(
        new SelectListItem[] 
        { 
              new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "" , Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Mark", Text = "Mark" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Jim", Text = "Jim" },
              new SelectListItem { Value = "Jason", Text = "Jason" }                                 
        },

        "Value", 
        "Text",
        Model
    )
) %>
```

In the model class I have ..

```
 [UIHint("NameDropDown")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

In Create View - Name Dropdown renders properly and I am able to pick a value and save to DB. When I go back to my List view and Click on Edit, the Edit View does not show me Name value from the database. (DB has the name value in the table).

Comment: have you tried removing `Selected = true`?

Comment: Its just not binded to the field in the model. I took away the empty choices and it shows me the first choice for any row I want to Edit.

Comment: Its something to do with the editor template I am using for the dropdown. All other fields that do not need to be dropdown in the views dont have this issue.

Comment: If I change Html.EditorFor to Html.DisplayFor - it works fine. It gets the value of the field from the database and populates it on the Edit view.. but EditorFor tries to render the dropdown from the editor template and it messes up the binding somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the model type (string) in your template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"%>
```

Change this to:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>"%>
```

I just ran a local test, and it works fine.